# .NET MAUI project not compiling target android MSB4057: The target 'UpdateGeneratedFiles' does not exist in the project

Tags: c#, android, xaml, maui, csproj

I am building a .NET MAUI app and I have found this error when trying to build and run the app but it was running normally when I ran the template it comes with but now it is giving this error: MSB4057: The target 'UpdateGeneratedFiles' does not exist in the project.

Here is my MainPage.xaml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ToDoMAUIClient.MainPage">


</ContentPage>
```

here is my Project.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>ToDoMAUIClient</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>ToDoMAUIClient</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.todomauiclient</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>d0e774d6-0ec2-4307-8314-b664a5b61b51</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="Platforms\Android\Resources\xml\network_security_config.xml" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I tried to look for this error MSB4057 and it says it is related to resources paths mispelled or not found even on the microsoft error reference it is saying it but I cannot find the resource 'UpdateGeneratedFiles'  or where it was used when I click in the error visual studio leads me to the first line of my csproj file.

Comment: I create a new project and change my csproj file based on yours but I can't reproduce your problem. Did you try to clean and rebuild the project or restart the VS?

Comment: What has changed since the last time you remember it working correctly?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a transient issue; it comes as goes for me. The latest time was after I modified the splash and icon svg files and manually adjusted the `BaseSize` for the splash screen in the `csproj` file.
I was able to get by it by closing VS, deleting the `obj` and `bin` folders in my project's main folder, relaunching, cleaning and rebuilding before attempting to start the project.

Note: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 (17.8.0) Preview 2.0, and a preview version of .net 8, but I presume the suggestion should be the same for earlier versions.

Comment: I am seconding that. I am getting this error after changing the platform icons. I too am on VS 2022 albeit v17.7.3. I had to restart VS as well, just cleaning and rebuilding did not fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A **file that does not exist** is routed in your `csproj`.

Remove this tag from your **Project.csproj** :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="Platforms\Android\Resources\xml\network_security_config.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You probably Add the `network_security_config.xml` file and then deleted it. Finally it cannot find that file during execution.